# Which maps should I bake to bring a geometry smoothness to a low-poly stylized character?

Tags: modeling, mesh, texture-baking, baking, polycount

The low poly stylized character model has about a 30k faces and a high poly one about 800k.
I tried to bake normal maps and also AO and curvature, but there is no smoothness (especially at the area of fingers and fingernails).
There's nothing plugged in the displacement nest (should I bake it too or not ?).
Maybe my model has too low polygons ?
Thanks for help.

Comment: You should bake a normal map, with selected to active (low poly) enabled